# How do i join custom object to a string

Tags: string, powershell

I want to test paths exist.  I've written the following script but i cant add string to custom object. This is the offending line `$DesktopCheck = | $FName + "\desktop"`.  How do i add the string "desktop" to custom object $fname?

```
$FoldNames = dir \\server\RedirectedFolders | Select-Object fullname 

foreach ($FName  in $FoldNames)
{
     $DesktopCheck = | $FName + "\desktop"
     Test-Path $DesktopCheck 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Join-Path` for constructing paths. It helps avoiding headaches caused by having to keep track of leading/trailing backslashes. I would also recommend using the option `-LiteralPath` unless you need wildcards/patterns in the match. Try this:

```
dir \\server\RedirectedFolders | % {
  Test-Path -LiteralPath (Join-Path $_.FullName "desktop")
}
```

Comment: The results are not correctly formatted paths.  This is a example result 
@{FullName=\\server\RedirectedFolders\Alan.Richardson}\desktop.  I want the result to be \\server\RedirectedFolders\Alan.Richardson\desktop.

Comment: Thanks. Just what i wanted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$FoldNames = dir \\server\RedirectedFolders | Select-Object -ExpandProperty fullname 

foreach ($FName  in $FoldNames)
  {
     Join-Path -Path $FName -ChildPath '\desktop'
     Test-Path $DesktopCheck 
  }
```